# Neighborhood system verification for a partially ordered set $(X,\leq)$.

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to verify that the following satisfies the axioms for a neighborhood system:

Let $(X,\leq)$ be a partially ordered set.

Define $S_r(x)=\{y\mid x\leq y\}$ and $\mathcal{U}_x=\{U(x)\mid S_r(x)\subseteq U(x)\}$. Then $\mathcal{U}_x$ is a neighborhood system at $x$. In particular, I am trying to verify the fourth axiom:

(iv) If $U(x)\in\mathcal{U}_x$, then there exists $V\in \mathcal{U}_x$ such that if $y\in V$, then $U(x) \in \mathcal{U}_y$.

So I assume that $U(x)\in \mathcal{U}_x$. This means that $S_r(x)\subseteq U(x)$. I need to choose $V\in \mathcal{U}_x$ satisfying the property. This is where I get stuck.

Comment: $S_r(x)$ is a bad notation, there is no $r$ involved and it suggests a metric setting where there is not. I prefer $x^\uparrow$ or $[x,\rightarrow)$ (the latter for a linear order).

Answer (score 1):

Try $V = x^\uparrow = \{y: x \le y\}$. By the definition of the neighbourhood system we know that $x^\uparrow \subseteq U(x)$, If $y \in V$ it's clear that $y^\uparrow \subseteq x^\uparrow \subseteq U$ and so $U \in \mathcal{U}_y$

Comment: Why choose the same set that was defined in the problem? Is it always the case that we can choose this set? Also, why does $y\in V \implies y^\uparrow \subseteq x^\uparrow$? I see that $y\in V\implies x\leq y$ but I don't see where $y^\uparrow$ came from.

Comment: @Jb23 $y \in V = x^\uparrow$ means $y \ge x$ so if $z \in y^\uparrow$ we have $z \ge y \ge x$ so $z \ge x$ (transitivity) and so $z \in x^\uparrow$. Hence $y^\uparrow \subseteq x^\uparrow$ and so now we have shown $$\forall y \in V: y^\uparrow \subseteq U$$ so that $V \in \mathcal{U}_y$ by definition.